# Alloc Traits File Error

Tags: c++

In my program, I am rolling five dice that are randomly chosen from the following possible sizes: 4-sided, 6-sided, 8-sided, 10-sided, 12-sided, 20-sided, and 100-sided. When I compile my header file and implementation file, the "alloc_traits.h" file opens. I'm new to C++ and I have never seen this before. What is its purpose and why is this file opening when I try to compile? Here are my header and main files.

**Header**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

class Die
{
private:
   int num_faces;
    int face_value;
public:
    Die ()
    {
        int face_value = 1;
        int num_faces = 1;
    }
        Die (int size)
    {
            num_faces = size;
    } 
        int roll()
    {
            return rand()%num_faces + 1;
    }
        int get_face_value()
    {
            return roll();
    }
        int get_num_faces()
    {
            return num_faces;
    }
};
```

**MAIN**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "header.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    //4,6,8,10,12,20,100


    vector<int> die_sizes;
    die_sizes.push_back(4);
    die_sizes.push_back(6);
    die_sizes.push_back(8);
    die_sizes.push_back(10);
    die_sizes.push_back(12);
    die_sizes.push_back(20);
    die_sizes.push_back(100);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5 ;++i)
        {
            int random_index = rand()%die_sizes.size();
            Die die(die_sizes.at(random_index));
            die.roll();
            cout << "d" << die_sizes.at(random_index) << " = " << die.get_face_value() << ", ";
        }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'pops up'?

Comment: The file opens.

Comment: You mean opens in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, it opens in C++

Comment: Note that you should add an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).